# Multitenancy with Micronaut for JDBC without Hibernate/JPA or GORM

Tags: multi-tenant, micronaut

Im working with Micronaut and Im trying to implement the Multitenancy feature for my app. My goal is to implement it with java in DATABASE mode for many oracle DBs, however all the info I found is related to spring, hibernate/jpa or gorm and I don't want/can't use any of those.... is it possible to achieve this? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not now, multitenancy is planned for the next major release of Micronaut Data

Comment: Thanks @Denis that make sense, where can I found the official releases page, to the aprox release date ??

Comment: 3.X releases are done every 6 weeks https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/wiki/Release-Schedule

Answer (score 2):

You can implement multitenancy using the repository per database technic:

```java
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}

@JdbcRepository(dataSource = "db1", dialect = Dialect.ORACLE)
interface Db1PersonRepository extends PersonRepository {
}

@JdbcRepository(dataSource = "db2", dialect = Dialect.ORACLE)
interface Db2PersonRepository extends PersonRepository {
}
```

Or the second option (only available starting from Micronaut Data 3.5.0) is to specify the database on the inject point:

```java
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.ORACLE)
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}

@Singleton
class MyService {

   @Inject
   @Repository("db1")
   PersonRepository db1PersonRepository

   @Inject
   @Repository("db2")
   PersonRepository db2PersonRepository
}
```

In the future, it should be possible to have GORM-style multitenancy.

Comment: Can you do this without having the set of tenants/datasources hardcoded?